Using flask to link to mysql
My teacher gave me a task to link a form that takes name and email address made with flask and html. He said to link it to a database in mysql. This data base will store the information received from the form. How do I set up the database such that the name and email obtained will show on a table in the database.
I have looked at websites GeekForGeeks but they all type out the name and other details they want to add to the table in the code which isn't what I want.

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Check out this. It is not perfect, and you might need to do some tweaking to get everything to work correctly, but it helped me. If you scroll down there is a table of contents, with a link to the chapter on databases.

First you will have to install Rowling packages using pip install package_name:

Flask (flask)
Flask SQLAlchemy (flask_sqlalchemy)
MySQL (mysql)

Sharing a code example of an admin template with you, hope this helps you in solving the problem.
admin.php
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>Admin register</title>
    <style>
        .register-form {
            width: 500px;
            margin: 0 auto;
            text-align: center;
            padding: 10px;
            color: #fff;
            background: #396;
            border-radius: 10px;
            -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
            -moz-border-radius: 10px;
        }

        .register-form form input {
            padding: 5px;
        }

        .register-form .btn {
            padding: 5px;
            border-radius: 5px;
            text-decoration: none;
            width: 100px;
            display: inline-block;
            color: #fff;
            background: #36f;
        }

        .register-form .register {
            border: 0;
            width: 60px;
            padding: 8px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="register-form">
    <h1>Admin Register</h1>
    <form action="adminregister.php" method="POST">
        <p><label>E-Mail :</label>
            <input id="email" type="email" name="email" required/></p>

        <p><label>Password :</label>
            <input id="password" type="password" name="password" required/></p>
        <span id="message"></span>

        <input class="btn register" id="adminsubmit" type="submit" name="submit" value="Register"/>
        <span id="message"></span>
    </form>
</div>
</body>
</html>

admin.py

from flask import Blueprint, render_template, Flask, request, session, redirect, url_for
import pymysql
pymysql.install_as_MySQLdb()
from flask_mysqldb import MySQL
import MySQLdb.cursors
import re 

admin = Blueprint("admin", __name__, static_folder="static", template_folder="templates")
app = Flask(__name__)
app.secret_key = 'bb2fb443b5d32e26c08ba803de5beab1'

app.config['MYSQL_HOST'] = 'localhost'
app.config['MYSQL_USER'] = 'root'
app.config['MYSQL_PASSWORD'] = ''
app.config['MYSQL_DB'] = 'adminpythonlogin'

mysql = MySQL(app)


@admin.route('/main')
def adminindex():
    return render_template('adminhome.html')

@admin.route('/adminpythonlogin/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def adminlogin():
    msg = ''
    if request.method == 'POST' and 'adminusername' in request.form and 'adminpassword' in request.form:
        adminusername = request.form['adminusername']
        adminpassword = request.form['adminpassword']
        cursor = mysql.connection.cursor(MySQLdb.cursors.DictCursor)
        cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM adminaccounts WHERE adminusername = %s AND adminpassword = %s', (adminusername, adminpassword,))
        adminaccount = cursor.fetchone()
        if adminaccount:
            session['adminloggedin'] = True
            session['adminid'] = adminaccount['adminid']
            session['adminusername'] = adminaccount['adminusername']
            return redirect(url_for('admin.adminhome'))
        else:
            msg = 'Incorrect username/password!'
    return render_template('adminindex.html', msg=msg)

@admin.route('/adminpythonlogin/adminlogout')
def adminlogout():
    session.pop('adminloggedin', None)
    session.pop('adminid', None)
    session.pop('adminusername', None)
    return redirect(url_for('adminlogin'))

@admin.route('/adminpythonlogin/adminregister', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def adminregister():
    msg = ''
    if request.method == 'POST' and 'adminusername' in request.form and 'adminpassword' in request.form and 'adminemail' in request.form:
        adminusername = request.form['adminusername']
        adminpassword = request.form['adminpassword']
        adminemail = request.form['adminemail']
        cursor = mysql.connection.cursor(MySQLdb.cursors.DictCursor)
        cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM adminaccounts WHERE adminusername = %s', (adminusername,))
        adminaccount = cursor.fetchone()
        if adminaccount:
            msg = 'Account already exists!'
        elif not re.match(r'[^@]+@[^@]+\.[^@]+', adminemail):
            msg = 'Invalid email address!'
        elif not re.match(r'[A-Za-z0-9]+', adminusername):
            msg = 'Username must contain only characters and numbers!'
        elif not adminusername or not adminpassword or not adminemail:
            msg = 'Please fill out the form!'
        else:
            cursor.execute('INSERT INTO adminaccounts VALUES (NULL, %s, %s, %s)', (adminusername, adminpassword, adminemail,))
            mysql.connection.commit()
            msg = 'You have successfully registered!'
    elif request.method == 'POST':
        msg = 'Please fill out the form!'
    return render_template('adminregister.html', msg=msg)

@admin.route('/adminpythonlogin/adminhome')
def adminhome():
    if 'adminloggedin' in session:
        return render_template('adminhome.html', adminusername=session['adminusername'])
    return redirect(url_for('adminlogin'))

@app.route('/adminpythonlogin/adminprofile')
def adminprofile():
    if 'adminloggedin' in session:
        cursor = mysql.connection.cursor(MySQLdb.cursors.DictCursor)
        cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM adminaccounts WHERE adminid = %s', (session['adminid'],))
        account = cursor.fetchone()
        return render_template('adminprofile.html', account=account)
    return redirect(url_for('adminlogin'))

adminpythonlogin.sql
CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS `adminpythonlogin` DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci;
USE `adminpythonlogin`;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `adminaccounts` (
    `adminid` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `adminusername` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
    `adminpassword` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    `adminemail` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`adminid`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=2 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

INSERT INTO `adminaccounts` (`adminid`, `adminusername`, `adminpassword`, `adminemail`) VALUES (1, 'test', 'test', 'test@test.com');

SELECT * FROM adminaccounts;

